# How to get ether amount from state change of a ERC-721 transaction? (web3 py)

Tags: erc-721, web3.py, price, state

I am looking at this NFT token transfer:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe20b03eaa2ec1062dcdda2057b604a8d5f38b2f863342675c6fe38f8d6324a6c/advanced#statechange

When I fetch the transaction, it only returns info related to gas:

```
{'blockHash': '0x2cc4381b2d25bfef85d085b81349e78f660db44883881b19b5d19adc8ead40ca',
  'blockNumber': '14231373',
  'confirmations': '1251629',
  'contractAddress': '0xf1bcbd895aa92a64a2728fa5b42afd35642aa6b9',
  'cumulativeGasUsed': '8309171',
  'from': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  'gas': '133393',
  'gasPrice': '140749760046',
  'gasUsed': '133393',
  'hash': '0xe20b03eaa2ec1062dcdda2057b604a8d5f38b2f863342675c6fe38f8d6324a6c',
  'input': 'deprecated',
  'nonce': '12',
  'timeStamp': '1645204461',
  'to': '0x3ab28be10ab2fb047ddca4e099372da66671e5f9',
  'tokenDecimal': '0',
  'tokenID': '566',
  'tokenName': 'MetaMoose',
  'tokenSymbol': 'MTMS',
  'transactionIndex': '140'},
```

but I need the mint price and on etherscan, i can only see the ether prices in "state change"

How can I find this state change info using web3.py?

I only found things about state trie online and don't understand how to fetch the mint prices or transfer prices from such erc-721 transactions

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is done so by decoding the `input` from the tx, which i didn't have in this case.
I switched to quicknode and now it has `value` which returns the price of a mint or transfer of a ERC-721 token